# python , walking directory of existing script that doesn't

Tags: python

I was looking to do an similar script to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530237/find-files-in-a-directory-containing-desired-string-in-python) however noticed that when I ran the linked question it only looks at files within the root of the directory provided. can anyone give the best way to walk all the directory's in a folder (presuming you had something like the following):

c:\test c:\test\1 c:\test\2

and so on and wanted to search all files and folders in all folders not just the root

Comment: Search the Python documentation for `os.walk()`

Comment: If you are using Python 3.5+, you can use the `pathlib` module, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186565/6279885). In my opinion It is both intuitive and powerful!

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path
r=Path(r"c:\\").rglob('system')
next(r)
```

or you can use 'for' to loop r.